# How do i copy sql database file from a system location to another?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a database file at location in system `/user_setting/rw/audioproperties.db`.

I want to copy this database file into a location `/data/data/`.

Working with C++.

Comment: An sqlite database has nothing especial, is just another file.

Comment: Does your C++ program need to do this? In that case, be sure the database isn't being modified by a query.

Comment: Yeah I make sure of the database closure before starting the copying operation

Answer (score -1):

```
while(!feof(factory_db)) 
        {
            ch = fgetc(factory_db);
            if(ferror(factory_db))
            {
                ;
            }
            if (!feof(factory_db)) 
            {
                fputc(ch, backup_set_db);
                if (ferror(backup_set_db)) 
                {
                    ;
                    fclose(backup_set_db);
                    fclose(factory_db);
                }
            }
        }
```